# Intellij IDEA - Actionscript Project - Adding External Library Source Path

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, intellij-idea, flash-builder

I have created a Module Library pointing to source folder, which contains all my packages of .as files  like TweenMax, BulkLoader etc.

Project Settings > Modules > Select or Add Module > Add Content Root

But When I compiled, It doesn't detect those Module Library files and throws errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by selecting "Sources" option of (Sources, Test Sources). Project Settings > Modules > Select or Add Module > Add Content Root > Select "Sources"